# error: the following arguments are required: --path An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

Tags: ipython, data-science

project on https://github.com/linouk23/NBA-Player-Movements. Could you please let me know how to execute this project? I'm new to python. It'll help me to kick start my work on project. I'm executing my project on Spyder and installed all necessary libraries. I'm getting error as

usage: main.py [-h] --path PATH [--event EVENT]
main.py: error: the following arguments are required: --path
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

Answer (score 2):

**For windows:**

Open the extracted folder and press "**shift + right click**" and from there "**Open command window here**".

In cmd enter **python main.py**

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried in Jupyter Notebook and it failed, then I copied it in a .py file and run (Ubuntu) in terminal ,it worked.
I don't know how to solve the problem but I can 'avoid' this.

Answer (score 0):

For the ones who are receiving this error, another thing to check is the way you are passing the arguments. Arguments are passed by adding two leading hyphens. So, when the error says

> following arguments are required: example_arg

your code should be
`parser.add_argument('--example_arg', 'arg1')`. Note the two leading hyphens `--`